# How to connect one set of fans to two motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, fan

I have a dual system case (one Windows and one Linux).

Currently, I have two sets of fans. If I start only one system, I have only set of fans. 
But I would like all the case fans (CPU fans would still be linked to each system) to be started regardless of the system that is running.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a 12v 2a power supply, and wire all the fans to that. You will have to manually turn on the fans using a separate switch though, which would only be problematic if you forget to turn them on. The fans would be at 100% unless you also wire in a fan speed controller - you can buy these that fit into a 5.25 cd bay. I am also assuming that you have 4 fans at 0.3a per fan. Most fans don't go over 0.5a

Comment: I didn't think of that! That's a good idea! Is there more than 2A power supplies like this? I plan to have many fans.

Comment: 12v 3a or 5a power supplies come with a lot of flat screen monitors. Pretty much available everywhere